# C# Regex, can i set MaxValue instead of MaxLength on my string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to make a textbox in UWP only allow the following input: 9 digits, followed by a '.' (optional), followed by 2 digits (optional), by using Regex.

So far i have come up with an expression that allows 9 digits, or 9 digits and a '.'

```
string pattern = @"^(?<Number>([0-9]{0,9})(\.?)([0-9]{0,2}?))";
```

I want it to accept `123456789` or `123456789.12` as inputs.

But now it only accepts `123456789` or `123456789.`

Comment: Are you using bindings?

Comment: You did not add `$` at the end, so your regex matches strings that *start* with your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match 2 optional digits you could make the group optional `(?:[0-9]{2})?` because `[0-9]{0,2}` Matches 0, 1 or 2 digits.

The same goes for `{0,9}` which matches from 0 - 9 times a digit.

To match the whole pattern you should add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string.

If you don't need the capturing groups you could update your pattern to:

```
^(?<Number>[0-9]{9}\.?(?:[0-9]{2})?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKU7Wc/1)